# How can I unite attachments of generic type event handlers?

Tags: c#, generics, events, event-handling, eventhandler

I have an interface for an animal, and I have some classes that implement the interface.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    int LegCount { get; }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public int LegCount { get { return 4; } }
}

public class Octopus : IAnimal
{
    public int LegCount { get { return 8; } }
}
```

I have a generic EventArgs class that has an instance of an animal of the specified type.

```
public class AnimalRequiredEventArgs<TAnimal> : EventArgs
    where TAnimal : class, IAnimal
{
    public TAnimal Animal { get; set; }
}
```

I have a class that has events that require an instance of an animal of the specified type.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler<AnimalRequiredEventArgs<Dog>> DogRequired;
    public event EventHandler<AnimalRequiredEventArgs<Octopus>> OctopusRequired;
}
```

I have a class that has an event handler that sets an animal of the specified type to the generic property of the event args.

```
public class AnimalsManager
{
    private readonly IList<IAnimal> _animals =
        new List<IAnimal>{new Dog(), new Octopus()};

    public void OnAnimalRequired<TAnimal>(object sender, AnimalRequiredEventArgs<TAnimal> e)
        where TAnimal : class, IAnimal
    {
        e.Animal = _animals.OfType<TAnimal>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

How can I unite attachments of generic type event handlers as shown below?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var manager = new AnimalsManager();
        var mine = new MyClass();

        // How can I unite these event handler attachments?
        mine.DogRequired += manager.OnAnimalRequired;
        mine.OctopusRequired += manager.OnAnimalRequired;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this is to create Animal Class:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    int LegCount { get; }
}

public abstract class Animal: IAnimal
{
     public virtual int LegCount {get{return 4;}}   

     public event EventHandler<AnimalRequiredEventArgs<Animal>> AnimalRequired;

     protected virtual void OnAnimalRequired(AnimalRequiredEventArgs e)
        {
            // Make a temporary copy of the event to avoid possibility of
            // a race condition if the last subscriber unsubscribes
            // immediately after the null check and before the event is raised.
            EventHandler<AnimalRequiredEventArgs<Animal>> handler = AnimalRequired;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override int LegCount { get { return 4; } }
}

public class Octopus : IAnimal
{
    public override int LegCount { get { return 8; } }
}
```

Then you can override OnAnimalRequired in each of the derived class if you want to.

For clients, there would be a single event exposed from abstract base class.

Hope this helps.